# How to change extension of string path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

Below is my string value

```
string strFile = @"http://login.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto4dvsf5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.doc";
```

And I need to replace this file path value by

```
http://login.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto4dvsf5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.pdf
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string strFile = @"http://login.contentraven.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto4dvsf5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.DOC";

string strTemp = Path.GetExtension(strFile).ToLower();

if (strTemp==".doc")
{
    strFile = Path.ChangeExtension(strFile, "pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
string pdfFile = Path.ChangeExtension(strFile, ".pdf");
```

Comment: You"re welcome. I just deleted my comment since you updated your answer :-) ...so +1 now :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) of `Path.ChangeExtension` states: _If neither path nor extension contains a period (.), ChangeExtension adds the period._ So wether or not you have the period in the second argument, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Like this for example

```
string strFile = @"http://login.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto4dvsf5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.doc";
string newString = String.Format("http://login.com/Uploads/{0}", strFile.Split('/').Last());
```

Comment: This creates a string containing: http://login.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto4dvsf5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.doc

Comment: Sorry, I'm blind this morning. I magically saw the URL as the part to be replaced, not the extension. Path.ChangeExtension is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strFile=@"http://login.contentraven.com/Uploads/g05fgxeto5531yb3l45_16_8_2011_1_25_37.DOC";


string strTemp = Path.GetExtension(strFile).ToLower();

if (strTemp==".doc")
{
    strFile = Path.ChangeExtension(strFile, "pdf");
}
```